# Permutations with a sum constraint

Tags: python, performance, numpy, combinatorics, pandas

I have made the following function that gives the combinations permuted of n elements with a constrain/rule. This consist on creating a dataframe with all combination of numbers from 0 to n that sums n.

### Function

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np

def combinations_permuted(n_elm):
    items = list(range(0,n_elm+1,1))
    combinations = pd.DataFrame(list(filter(lambda x: np.sum(x)==n_elm,list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(items, n_elm)))))
    comb_permuted = pd.DataFrame()
    for index, combination in combinations.iterrows():
        comb_permuted=comb_permuted.append(list(filter(lambda x: np.sum(x)==n_elm,list(itertools.permutations(combination.tolist(), n_elm)))))

    return(comb_permuted.drop_duplicates().as_matrix())
```

### Example

```
array([[0, 0, 3],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [3, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

The problem is that is taking a long time when `n_elm` is "big" for example 9. I think this code can be improving in terms of time performance.

Maybe by replacing the `for` loop with a `map` function.

Any help to get it?

Comment: What Python version are you targeting?

Comment: try with https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969798/3308055

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> def combinations_permuted(n_elm):
> ```

IMO `n` (as used in the description of the code in the question) is more readable than `n_elm`.

> ```
>     items = list(range(0,n_elm+1,1))
> ```

`1` is the default step, and `range` isn't so obscure a function that the maintenance programmer would wonder what `range(0, n+1)` does.

> ```
>     combinations = pd.DataFrame(list(filter(lambda x: np.sum(x)==n_elm,list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(items, n_elm)))))
>     comb_permuted = pd.DataFrame()
>     for index, combination in combinations.iterrows():
>         comb_permuted=comb_permuted.append(list(filter(lambda x: np.sum(x)==n_elm,list(itertools.permutations(combination.tolist(), n_elm)))))
>
>     return(comb_permuted.drop_duplicates().as_matrix())
> ```

There are two things here which sound warning bells:

1. `comb_permuted=comb_permuted.append`. The documentation for [DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) says

   > Iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original DataFrame all at once.
2. `drop_duplicates()`. That says that the generation process is doing more work that it needs to.

A KISS approach would be to replace the `combinations_with_replacement`, `permutations`, `drop_duplicates` chain with `itertools.product`. This is much faster at `n = 3`, but already slower at `n = 5` (because it's still doing more work that it needs to, and filtering).

The efficient approach is to do only the work that's necessary. A quick and dirty implementation (i.e. please tidy it up before using) calculates for `n = 6` in less time than it takes the original code to calculate `n = 3`:

```
def combinations_recursive_inner(n, buf, gaps, sum, accum):
  if gaps == 0:
    accum.append(list(buf))
  else:
    for x in range(0, n+1):
      if sum + x + (gaps - 1) * n < n: continue
      if sum + x > n: break
      combinations_recursive_inner(n, buf + [x], gaps - 1, sum + x, accum)

def combinations_recursive(n):
  accum = []
  combinations_recursive_inner(n, [], n, 0, accum)
  return pd.DataFrame(accum).as_matrix()
```

[Online test and benchmark](https://repl.it/repls/LimitedHardtofindCones)